# Unable to compare a JavaScript variable with JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, html, local-storage, object-comparison

I have a table stored as a string in a JSON data in **localstorage**. I want to compare one of fields stored here to a separate javascript variable.

Here is what I have tried:

```
var goalsStr = localStorage.getItem("goals");
var goalsObj = JSON.parse(goalsStr); 
for (i=0; i<goalsObj.goals.length; i++) {
  if (goal==goalsObj.goals[i].goal) {
    //.....
    //.....
  }
}
```

But it is not working. After some trouble shooting, I **think** that the problem is in comparing `(goal == goalsObj.goals[i].goal)`.

And this is the value that was actually stored inside "goals" in localStorage:

```
var data = '{"goals": [{"goal":"'+goal+'","duedate":"'+date2+'","noofdays":"'+diff+'","active":"'+active+'"}]}';
localStorage.setItem("goals",data);
```

It is an array of objects stored within.

All these 'diff', 'duedate' are HTML form data taken from users.

What's wrong? What should I do?

Comment: We cannot really help you if we don't know the value of `goalsObj` or `goal`. You also have to explain what exactly you are trying to achieve and what the problem is. Do you *think* that the problem is the comparison or do you *know* it? FYI, the problem doesn't seem to have anything to do with JSON (unless the problem is generating proper JSON in the first place).

Comment: It depends on what is `goal` and its type. Suppose they are object/array then they can not be compared with ==.

Comment: You will have to show us EXACTLY what was stored in localStorage.

Comment: @FelixKling I have edited the question to answer your concerns.

Comment: @blunderboy Yes. They do involved Objects and Arrays. If not with == then what else should I use?

Comment: @jfriend00 I have edited the question and now you can see the data stored in localStorage.

Comment: Why are you calling JSON.stringify on a string?  You should call JSON.stringify on a javascript object.  What you're going to get back from `JSON.parse()` is a string, not a javascript object.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have made that change, It's still not workin.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/fLd5T/

Comment: @user221287 - simple debugging is where you start.  Look at goalsObj in the debugger and see if it's exactly what you are expecting it to be.  If not, you will know your next problem.  If it is, then step through each comparison in your `for` loop and see why none are matching your goal variable.

Comment: @tom Is it possible to store the localStorage in one file and acess it in a seperate file?

Comment: @tom http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20368160/can-localstorage-data-created-and-saved-in-one-html-file-can-be-used-in-another

Comment: @user221287 Yes, but looks like you already got an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Data appears to already be valid JSON.  Why are you stringifying it?  I think you want to do just

```
var data = '{"goals": [{"goal":"'+goal+'","duedate":"'+date2+'","noofdays":"'+diff+'","active":"'+active+'"}]}';
localStorage.setItem("goals", data);
```

and then when you pull that value back out, convert it to a JavaScript object via

```
var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("goals"));
```

Comment: Yes. You are absolutely right. But still I am not getting the output desired. There has to be some other error as well.

Comment: @user221287 - at this point you're just going to have to add some `debugger;` statements, run the code with the dev tools window open, and just step through it and see what's wrong.  Your code looks ok, you likely made a silly mistake when splicing together that json string.

Comment: Is this the possible problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20368160/can-localstorage-data-created-and-saved-in-one-html-file-can-be-used-in-another

Comment: Possibly - are you trying to access this piece of data on a different domain?

Comment: No. not on a different domain, but in a different .html file in my laptop. My whole project is offline.