# Can localStorage data created and saved in one HTML file can be used in another HTML file?

Tags: html, local-storage

I am creating a completely offline HTML5 app using localStorage.

I have successfully saved and retrieved and manipulated localStorage data in a single .HTML file. Anyhow, now when I am trying to access localSotrage data stored by one .HTML file on another .HTML file, I am getting no success.

Anyhow, I have created a separate .html file to clear all the localStorage, and that one is working fine.

Is it because localStorage of each web page is separate and cannot be put together or some other error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In HTML5, is the localStorage object isolated per page/domain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201239/in-html5-is-the-localstorage-object-isolated-per-page-domain)

Answer (score 3):

localStorage is controlled by same-origin policy
Assuming you're using `file://` it varies by browser:

Webkit:

All `file://` documents have the same origin
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=20701

Mozilla:

> In Gecko 1.8 or earlier, any two file: URIs are considered to be
>   same-origin.  In other words, any HTML file on your local disk can
>   read any other file on your local disk.
>
> Starting in Gecko 1.9, files are allowed to read only certain other
>   files.  Specifically, a file can read another file only if the parent
>   directory of the originating file is an ancestor directory of the
>   target file. Directories cannot be loaded this way, however.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same-origin_policy_for_file:_URIs

IE:

Doesnt apply (see: [localStorage object is undefined in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392032/localstorage-object-is-undefined-in-ie))